# scikit-learn StackingClassifier: are only sklearn estimators supported?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm considering using scikit-learn's [sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.html).

I read the documentation, but it is really not clear to me which estimators are supported by StackingClassifier.

Are estimators not part of sklearn (catboost, keras, pytorch, etc) compatible with StackingClassifier?

If some of them are, what are the minimum and sufficient requirements for an estimator to work with the StackingClassifier?

Answer (score 1):

sklearn uses its own estimator API so you will need to make your model (whether it is catboost, keras, ...) compatible with this API.

sklearn provides a way to implement your own sklearn compatible estimator or wrap an existing model in such a way that it will be compatible. The way to do this is to extend sklearn's `BaseEstimator` class and provide implementation for required methods (such as `fit` and `predict`). Here is a simple example taken from docs.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_X_y, check_array, check_is_fitted
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import unique_labels
from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances
class TemplateClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):

    def __init__(self, demo_param='demo'):
        self.demo_param = demo_param

    def fit(self, X, y):

        # Check that X and y have correct shape
        X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
        # Store the classes seen during fit
        self.classes_ = unique_labels(y)

        self.X_ = X
        self.y_ = y
        # Return the classifier
        return self

    def predict(self, X):

        # Check is fit had been called
        check_is_fitted(self)

        # Input validation
        X = check_array(X)

        closest = np.argmin(euclidean_distances(X, self.X_), axis=1)
        return self.y_[closest]
```

You can find more info [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html).